# Adding functionality to ToggleButton,

Tags: android, togglebutton

I am making a graphic intensive application on Android. I have to make a button for enabling and disabling sound of the application, which is pretty common amongst apps. I actually cannot find the correct way to do it. I have managed to switch the image through xml files but am still lost about how to add a functionality to those.

code is below ..
Main Layout

```
<Button android:id="@+id/InfoButton" android:background="@drawable/infoiconlow" android:layout_gravity="top|left" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="30dp" android:layout_marginTop="2dp" android:layout_marginLeft="125dp"></Button>
    <Button android:layout_gravity="top|right" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/ForwardButton" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/forwardbuttonlow" android:layout_marginRight="10dp" android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"></Button>
    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/selectthescenetitle" android:id="@+id/imageView3" android:layout_gravity="top|center" android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" android:layout_marginTop="-3dp" android:layout_width="219dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
    <ToggleButton android:id="@+id/MusicButton" android:background="@drawable/shufflebutton" android:textOn="" android:textOff="" android:layout_gravity="top|left" android:layout_width="30dp" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_marginTop="2dp" android:layout_marginLeft="84dp" android:clickable="true"> 
    </ToggleButton>
```

sufflebutton.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/shufflebuttonimage" />   
</layer-list>
```

shufflebuttonimage.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/musiconiconlow" android:state_checked="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/musicofficonlow"/>
</selector>
```

The image toggles but if i go back and forth, the state resumes its default, and i am unable to add a functionality to the toggle e.g. enabling and disabling sound. Can anyone please help me out in solving this problems, its driving me crazy ..

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you mean you can't figure out how to respond to its state change events? Use [setOnCheckChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener))

Comment: i mean that i want the state of my toggle button according to the sound i.e. enabled or disabled PLUS when i tap the button, it sets toggles the state of the button aswell ...

can you guide me a little on it ..

Answer (score 0):

I usually implement some code like this:

```
private void initialise(final Context context)
{       
    final ToggleButton music = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.MusicButton);


    music.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {               
            music.setChecked(true);             
            // Do other stuff like play the music.
        }
    });
}
```

For full functionality you will probably have to checked the button's checked state before doing anything.

Comment: I am going to my University for few lectures, I would love to get back to you and try and implement it the right way ..